# Timestamp in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, orm, datestamp

I'm quite fresh in Hibernate, I just have run my first project with Hibernate.

But I want to insert some data in my Postgres DB, one of the column is `operationtime TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` , while I was doing this with Postgres I was using `current_timestamp(0)` to insert date. Wondering how to proceed in hibernate in order to insert date. How to do the map in my map XML file.

For example:

```
  <property name="time" type="java.util.Date">
    <column name="operationtime"/>
  </property>
```

I did some research but I wasn't able to find what I want, probably I'm missing something regarding date types in Hibernate. Any advice is welcome.

Comment: Storing a timestamp with time zone in a database is generally not advisable:

http://derickrethans.nl/storing-date-time-in-database.html

Answer (score 1):

[This code](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Hibernate/SaveDateType.htm) shows how to map a date/timestamp and to persist it. Have a look

Comment: Yes, but i m looking for a way the timestamp to be generated by the db not inserted by me.

Comment: why not generated from Java code just before persisting, as in that code ?